# Conditional Styling of an Angular component

Tags: angular

I am trying to style a component on basis of a condition in following way.

```
<div class="col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" ng-style ="{ ' background-color' : (vars.state=='Signup')? '#73c7af' : '#ffffff' }">
```

and my vars.state=Signup. So it according to this background of this div should be #73c7af but it still white. Can anybody tell me where I am making mistake?

Comment: post the content of vars

Comment: these are all vars


vars = {
    state: ''
  };
  
  signupData = {
    name:'',
    email:'',
    father_husband:'',
    address:'',
    cnic:'',
    cnincpath:''
  };

  signatureData= {
  name:'',
  signatureurl: ''
  }
  verification = {
    code:{
      digit1:'',
      digit2:'',
      digit3:'',
      digit4:'',
    },
    heading:'',
    message: {
      top:'',
      bottom:''
    },
    button:'next'
  }


And I am setting state to 'Signup' in constructor.

Comment: syntax for angular is `[ngStyle]="..."`

Comment: This Angular 2 or 1?

Comment: This is angular 2

Comment: @D.Simon same result

Comment: remove the space before `background-color` in your html. `[ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': vars.state=='Signup' ? '#73c7af' : '#ffffff' }"`

Comment: here is a link to working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Mk0lVnS3PDAIa7qNTwE5?p=preview

Comment: Thanks folks for your help!

Answer (score 145, accepted):

To conditionally style a DOM element, there are multiple options for Angular 2+:

### [NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

This is very similar to the AngularJS `ng-style` implementation and allows multiple styles by adding more object properties.

```
<div
  [ngStyle]="{'background-color': (vars.state=='Signup') ? '#73c7af' : '#ffffff'}"
></div>
```

### [Style binding](https://angular.io/guide/class-binding#binding-to-a-single-style)

Alternatively, you can use the `[style.]` binding syntax. If you want to set multiple different styles, you need to add the attribute multiple times.

```
<div
  [style.background-color]="(vars.state=='Signup') ? '#73c7af' : '#ffffff'"
  [style.color]="myColor"
></div>
```

Comment: <div class="col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" 
     [ngStyle]="{'backgroundColor': (vars.state=='Signup') ? '#73c7af' : '#ffffff'}">

this works also.

Answer (score 26):

You can use style.propertyName to set any conditional style property.

```
<div class="col-md-3 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" [style.background]="someFunction()">
```