# how to hide the scrollbar when a specific component is present

Tags: css, angular

I added this code at the index.html:

```
<head>
     <style>
        body::-webkit-scrollbar {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

and it hides the scrollbar completely. What I want to achieve is that when `jobs-component` is present, only then to be hidden. When another component is present, then show the scrollbar.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Styling of an Angular component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45484811/conditional-styling-of-an-angular-component)

Answer (score 0):

You could start by creating a CSS class to hide your overflow:

```
.no-scroll{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then you could implement the *OnInit* interface in your **jobs-component** and add your class to the body whenever the ngOnInit() fires:

```
 export class jobs-component implements OnInit {

   //SOME CODE HERE

   ngOnInit() {
     document.querySelector("body").classList.add("no-scroll");
   }

   //SOME CODE HERE
 }
```

Keep in mind that you probably should **remove the no-scroll class** from the body on component dismount (*ngOnDestroy()*, from the OnDestroy interface), as the overflow will remain hidden otherwise.